# How to attach a java agent to a remote JVM

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

I checked [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) link. However, looks like `VirtualMachine` class is no longer accessible or present in JDK 8.

How do I attach a Java agent to a remote running JVM? A good pointer or applicable code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: `However, looks like VirtualMachine class is no longer accessible or present in JDK 8` -
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html

Answer (score 2):

In JDK8, the class is only available in the `tools.jar` which you have to locate and load explicitly. This changes with Java 9 where the class is contained in its own module.

To ease the usage, you can look into [Byte Buddy agent](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22byte-buddy-agent%22) which offers APIs and auto-discovery for executing such a remote attach.